# UUID column autogenerated without @Id anotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, uuid

I have a table and there is already id defined, but for some reason I need the uuid column to be auto generated and unique.

I tried all kind of annotations like this, but nothing seems to work:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
```

Is it possible without defining uuid as @Id?
Thanks.

```
public class EntityClass {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private UUID uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did it this way:

```
public class EntityClass {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

On initial save, UUID will be set, and it should be unique and not null.